# Where should lookup tables be stored for serverless functions?

Tags: node.js, database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, lookup

I'm building my application using Google Cloud Functions and currently have a database. Each cloud function will query this table with different queries to standardize their information before adding it to the database. This doesn't feel good as the table is always static (may have manual changes done by me occasionally) so a database lookup feels slow and resource heavy. Also each cloud function uses a connection so the connection limit will be exhausted very fast, but I'm not sure if this would solve anything as it would still need a connection to input the data into the database. All it would do is remove the extra 1-3 calls to standardize the data.

Is storing this table in the database the best way? Or is it better to store it in a javascript array file or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to cache data, you can write the data to a file in the local `tmp` dir when your first load it. If the same container instance is used to run another instance of your Cloud Function, that file will still be there and you can read it. But: this is the same as keeping the data in memory, as `/tmp` is actually implemented as an RAM/in-memory disk. So you can also simply keep a variable around with the data.

Aside from that, there isn't really a lot you can cache in Cloud Functions. You could consider including the data in a file in your deployment, or in a local sqlite database that is part of your deployment. But that means you'll have to deploy the Cloud Functions again when the database changes, so it all depends on how frequently the data changes and what you're willing to do when that happens.

Comment: Thank you! I'll probably keep it in memory as a variable then. The data shouldn't change all to frequently and will definitely change less frequently than I make feature update in the functions it self so I could probably just include the data changes when I deploy the feature changes.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Just keep in mind that Cloud Functions manages the containers, and may not keep them around very long. If you want more control over that, consider using Cloud Run and setting a [minimum number of instances](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances). But of course, then you'll pay for those instances, even when there's no calls to the Cloud Function(s) on them. It's always a trade-off like that.

Comment: Yeah, that is sort of the reason I am using them. It helps with costs significantly as for the majority of my time I scale down to 0, but when users use the software it scales to plenty of instances. Cloud run seemed really good too, but when I started developing I must have missed it so I went with cloud functions which at a high level seems easier to manage.